Deligne/Milne Tannakian Categories, prop. 1.17
In Tannakian Categories (page 14, prop. 1.17) we are given the following:

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a rigid abelian tensor category. If $U$ is a subobject of $\mathbf{1}$, then $\mathbf{1} = U \oplus U^{\bot}$, where $U^{\bot} = \ker(\mathbf{1} \to U^{\vee})$. Consequently, $\mathbf{1}$ is a simple object if $\operatorname{End}(\mathbf 1)$ is a field.

In the proof, we start by considering the SES $$0 \to U \to \mathbf{1} \to V \to 0$$ where $V = \operatorname{coker}(U \to \mathbf{1})$.
We later on find that the following set of equivalences hold: $$T \otimes U = 0 \iff T \otimes U \to T \text{ is zero} \iff T \to U^{\vee} \otimes T \text{ is zero.}$$
Then, it is stated that $$T = \ker(X \to U^{\vee} \otimes X) \simeq U^{\bot} \otimes X.$$
Here, I believe I understand the first equality, but I don't understand why $\ker(X \to U^{\vee} \otimes X) \simeq U^{\bot} \otimes X$ holds. Are we somehow just tensoring the diagram one writes up for the kernel of $\mathbf{1} \to U^{\vee}$ with $X$? I am quite new to (in my world) more "advanced" category theory, so it feels like there perhaps is some elementary fact I am missing that might make this obvious.

The short answer to your question is yes. But now one has to understand why the tensor product of the kernel is isomorphic to the kernel of the tensor product

Notice that we have a functorial map from the tensor product of the kernel to the kernel of the tensor product (the other direction of the iso you wrote). This map is epi by the adjointness of the tensor product. The mono part is from the previous property.

Dear @Nulhomologous, thanks for your answer. Let me think about this =). Could you perhaps expand a little (if you have time)? I mean, we know that $\iota:U^{\perp} \to \mathbf{1}$ is mono. Hence $U^{\perp} \otimes X \overset{\iota \otimes \text{id}}{\to} \mathbf{1} \otimes X \simeq X$ is mono. Also, when tensoring, $U^{\vee} \otimes X \to U^{\vee} \otimes X$ is still the zero map. But which map is are you referring to as epi? I believe you mean that left-adjoints preserve epi, and $- \otimes X$ is left-adjoint to $\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y)$. But which map is $- \otimes X$ preserving as epi?

See the answer to the following question on math.stackexchange for a rewrite of the proof, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4954006/

@anon Yeah, thanks, I saw that =). If you permit me to ask; do you know why (later in the same proof) $U \otimes U = U$ implies that $U^{\bot} \otimes U = 0$?

Isn't it obvious? As I'm sure you know, you shouldn't post essentially the same question on two different sites.

I would of course not ask if I thought it was obvious, so no, it is not obvious (for me). Also, they are distinctly not the same question.

Very closely related however, ofc. You did happen to answer what I was asking for here in the other forum, which I am of course grateful for.

Let $T\subset U$. Then, as for $U$, $T\otimes T=T$,
and so $T\otimes U=0\implies T=0$.

Yeah, thanks, me and my advisor figured it out, and yes, when you see it, I agree that it is obvious. Although I am not sure how to show that the original sequence is split exact (when replacing $V$ with $U^{\bot}$).

I don't understand your last question.  What you have to show is that then $1=U\oplus U^\bot$, not that a sequence is split exact.

If you show that the original sequence is split exact, it follows that $\mathbf{1} \cong U \oplus U^{\perp}$ since $U^{\perp} \cong V$.

This does ofc not mean that one has to go about it this way; but I claim that it is one way to show what we want.
